# Sum of Binomial Coefficients?

Tags: proof-writing, binomial-coefficients

Question: Trying to find a proof of the following equation.

For any $m,n\in \mathbb{N}^0$,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{n+k}{k} = \binom{n+m+1}{m}.$$

I know that Vandermonde's identity might be useful but not sure where to start.

Comment: how about induction?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Write it as $$\sum_{k=0}^m \binom {n+k}{n}$$

And then use hockey stick identity

For reference see [Hockey stick identity](http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Combinatorial_identity#Vandermonde.27s_Identity)

Using hockey stick identity we get $$\sum_{k=0}^m \binom {n+k}{n}=\binom {n+m+1}{n+1}=\binom {n+m+1}{m}$$